# c# setting uploadFile content-Type

Tags: c#, post, file-upload

I am trying to create an api call to my server that will allow me to upload a .csv file.

client side code

```
string url = "http://testserver/testapi";
string filePath = @"C:\test.csv";
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{
    wc.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/plain");
    byte[] responseArray = wc.UploadFile(url, filePath);
}
```

server side code

```
string savePath = testSavePath;
foreach (string f in Request.Files.AllKeys)
{
    HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[f];
    file.SaveAs(savePath);
}
```

I am getting an exception on this line `byte[] responseArray = wc.UploadFile(url, filePath);`

The strange thing is that when I look at `Request` I see

`ContentType="multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------8d006b7c2a5452c"`.

Looking at the docs for UploadFile I see that a WebException will be thrown when `The Content-type header begins with multipart.`

My question is why is contentType getting set to multipart and how do I prevent it from doing so?

Comment: What exception are you getting?

Comment: Does it work if you remove `wc.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/plain");`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your client code seems ok. The exception may be coming from the server-side. But that's hard to judge as you did not share the exception. Please do, you will get better answers.

For the multipart content type: The `WebClient.UploadFile` uses value of `Content-Type` header for content type of the file (defaulting to `application/octet-stream` if not set), not a whole HTTP request. The actual HTTP request is always (as you have found) `multipart/form-data` (as per HTTP specification for uploading files) and you cannot (and should not) change it. The note in documentation refers to content type of the actual file. It means that you cannot ask `WebClient` to upload file that is multipart on its own (that would be wrapped in another multipart HTTP envelope).